# ThinkingSphinx - Search through has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a relationship between two models, `Idea` and `Iteration`. Each idea can have many iterations. The models looks like this;

```
# idea.rb
has_many :iterations, dependent: :destroy

# I also use with: :real_time 
after_save ThinkingSphinx::RealTime.callback_for(:idea)

# iteration.rb
belongs_to :idea
after_save ThinkingSphinx::RealTime.callback_for(:idea, [:idea])
```

My indexes for `Idea` looks like this:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :idea, :with => :real_time do
  [...]
  indexes iterations.title, as: :iteration_titles
  indexes iterations.description, as: :iteration_descriptions
  has iterations.id, :as => :iteration_ids, type: :integer
  [...]
end
```

And I search like this:

```
@ideas = @user.ideas.search  ThinkingSphinx::Query.escape(params[:search]),
  :with => {:team_id => @teams.collect(&:id)},
  :page     => params[:page],
  :per_page => 10,
  :order    => 'created_at DESC'
```

Currently, searching for either `Iteration` title or description returns **0** hits. And I have performed:

```
rake ts:rebuild
rake ts:regenerate
rake ts:index
```

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the differences between real-time indices and SQL-backed indices is that with SQL-backed indices, you refer to associations and columns in your index definition, but with real-time indices, you refer to methods.

And while `iterations` is an instance method within an `idea`, `title`, `description` and `id` are not methods on the object returned by `iterations`.

The easiest way to work through this has two parts. Firstly, add instance methods to Idea that return the data you want for the iteration-related fields and attributes:

```
def iteration_titles
  iterations.collect(&:title).join(' ')
end

def iteration_descriptions
  iterations.collect(&:description).join(' ')
end

def iteration_ids
  iterations.collect &:id
end
```

And then use those methods in your index definition:

```
indexes iteration_titles, iteration_descriptions
has iteration_ids, :type => :integer, :multi => true
```

And then, run `rake ts:regenerate` to get it all set up (`ts:rebuild` and `ts:index` have no meaning for real-time indices).